# MySQL right join with count not working properly

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have the following tables:
MOVIES

```
        +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | user_id     | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
        | title       | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | description | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | created_at  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | updated_at  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

MOVIE_VOTES

```
        +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id         | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | user_id    | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
        | movie_id   | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
        | like       | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | created_at | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
        | updated_at | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I want to query all the movies sorted by the number of likes they have. I have this query:

```
        SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count_likes 
        FROM movie_votes 
        RIGHT JOIN movies 
        ON movies.id=movie_votes.movie_id 
        WHERE movie_votes.like = 1 
        GROUP BY movie_id 
        ORDER BY count_likes;
```

And this returning the movies sorted by the number of likes BUT not the movies that haven't be voted(liked) yet. For some reason the RIGHT join works as simple join.
I have searched for some relative answers but cant find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a column name when doing *outer* joins so that it will count only the *non-null* values

```
SELECT  movies.id, 
        movies.user_id,
        movies.title,       
        movies.description, 
        movies.created_at,
        movies.updated_at,
        COUNT(movie_votes.movie_id) AS count_likes 
FROM    movies
        LEFT JOIN movie_votes  
            ON  movies.id = movie_votes.movie_id 
                AND movie_votes.like = 1
GROUP   BY movies.id, 
        movies.user_id,
        movies.title,       
        movies.description, 
        movies.created_at,
        movies.updated_at
ORDER   BY count_likes
```

The condition `movie_votes.like = 1` should be put in the `ON` clause so it will filter the rows in table `movie_votes` first before joining it to table `movies`.

Comment: Thank you John this was useful!